# SSRS and AD Groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I had a request come through asking me to create an AD Security group that could be used in SSRS for users to get reports. There are currently other AD groups that work but the one I have created does not allow users to connect. Creating AD groups isn't real difficult and I know I have it set up correctly. Does anyone have any input as to why the group is not working? I have no knowledge of SSRS or SQL in general so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does that group have any roles on SSRS?

Answer (score 5):

You have to assign that AD group an SSRS Role in SSRS Manager

[image]

Depending on permission you want to give it.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where SQL Server Reporting Services was failing to recognise recently added permissions on a group. Try the following:

- Clear the Kerberos cache on the client machine by running 'klist purge'
- Then completely restart the user's browser (don't just close the tab)

Fixed the problem here.